# How do I write a Linq to SQL query with a cast?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How do i write a Linq to SQL query that translates into the following:

```
SELECT CAST(DATETEXT AS datetime) FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dates = from row in mytable
            select DateTime.Parse(row.DATETEXT);
```

There are method overloads for [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) that allow you to specify a format.

Comment: But the DateTime.Parse will be executed on the client, not in the SQL database right? I was curious if it is possible to have the query translate it into a tsql CAST and have the sql server perform the casting.

Comment: @Peter: You could try a straight cast `(DataTime)row.DATETEXT`, and see what SQL is output.

Comment: I tried this, but tracing shows that it executes the following SQL statement: "SELECT [t0].[DATETEXT] FROM [mytable] AS [t0]". So casting is done in the client.

Answer (score -1):

actually, you won't be needing that. just parse it as datatime when you will use the field value. here is an exaple;

```
var query = from c in mytable
            select c;
```

then when you will use it;

```
DateTime _value = (DateTime)query.SingleOrDefault().DATETEXT
```

but if you wanna use it so much. here is an example;

```
NorthwindEntities _e = new NorthwindEntities();

public void poo() {

    var query = from e in _e.Products
                select DateTime.Parse(e.DateText);

}
```

Comment: I know this is fully possible, i was more interested to see if there is any cast in linq to sql that translates in to a TSQL CAST